# Inlining implementation of an interface

Tags: java

Is there a way to inline implementation of an interface without having its default constructor? To understand my question better, Lets say I have an interface MyInterface and one implementation of it called MyImplementation.

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    void myFunction();
}

public MyImplementation implements MyInterface
{
    private final String someString;

    public MyImplementation(String someString)
    {
         this.someString = someString;
    }

    public void myFunction()
    {
        // do something.
    }
}
```

Is there a way to inline MyImplementation? If I didn't have to pass someString to constructor of implementation I could just say -

```
MyInterface myInterface = new MyInterface() {
        public void myFunction()
        {
            // do something
        }
    };
```

Comment: Wait, do you want an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)?

Comment: Anonymous inner classes can access final variables of their containing scope. You could do `final String someString = "";`, then use `someString` inside of your second code sample

Comment: Yes, I meant anonymous class.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is how to make an anonymous class that references objects that you set up in the constructor, you could "inline" an implementation by making an anonymous class and reference `final` local variables defined in the same method, like this:

```
private final String someString = ...; // That's the string that you used to init in the constructor; init it here
MyInterface myInterface = new MyInterface() { // That's the code that you wanted to have
    public void myFunction()
    {
        System.out.println(someString); // This is allowed, because someString is final
    }
};
```

Behind the scene, Java compiler would generate a class that looks very much like your `MyImplementation` class, make a constructor that looks like your `MyImplementation` constructor, and pass `someString` to it.

Answer (score 0):

[Anonymous classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) are the "old" way to do this. The new way in Java 8, for an interface with exactly one method, is to use [lambda expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

For instance, let's say you wanted to print `someString`. Old way:

```
MyInterface o = new MyInterface() {
    @Override
    public void myFunction() {
        System.out.println(someString);
    }
};
```

new way:

```
MyInterface o = () -> System.out.println(someString);
```

You don't even need to make `someString` final with lambdas! It's good enough that it's "effectively final," which basically means that it could have been marked `final` and still compiled.

Comment: Yeah, Java 7 is *so* last year!

Comment: Is the objection that I mentioned a newer way, or that I described the old way as "old" (with quotes around it in the original, and everything!). It's not like I called anonymous classes _obsolete_.